# Как удалить элемент без идентификатора

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть `div`, который не имеет ни класса, ни `id` или `name`. Редактировать `html` код этого тега нельзя (то есть нельзя приписать ему идентификатор). Его нужно удалить со страницы. Есть какое-то решение?
Пример кода:

```
<div>Текст 1</div>
<div>Текст 2</div>
<div>Текст 3</div>
<div>Текст 4</div>
<div>Текст 5</div> <!-- этот элемент нужно удалить -->
```

Comment: вы сформулируйте словами критерий по которому его надо удалить. Если пятый див то одно решение, если содержащий какой-то текст, то другое.

Comment: Можно найти по содержимому? Это пожалуй для меня будет самым оптимальным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var arr = document.body.childNodes;
arr.forEach(i => {
  if (i.firstChild && i.firstChild.data == 'Текст 5') {
    i.remove();
  }
})
```

Может так?

Comment: Я тоже так сначала хотел с помощью массива, но у меня на странице ооочень много таких элементов. И считать их..

Comment: Да! Огромное спасибо! Это подходит!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.lastElementChild.remove()
```

Comment: mdn говорит что его нет в сафари, оформи сниппетом - проверим =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, 1. Не уверен. 2. Существует полифилл. 3. Можно заменить на `document.querySelector("body > :last-child")`. 4. `remove` тоже местами нет.

Comment: по крайней мере в сниппете тут - даже в хроме не работает, если делать у `body`, в диве - работает (хотел исправить твой ответ)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, потому что последним тегом в сниппете идёт сам <script>